# How to remove all markers except ones implemented with long click, using mMap.clear() in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am still learning android and struggle still with some parts.. so please bear with me! 
I have a spinner for my google maps, that removes all the markers and places new ones depending on what the user wants to see.

```
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
            "You have selected : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    if (selectedItem.equals("Landmarks")) {
        landMarkMarkers();
    } else if (selectedItem.equals("Trees")) {
        TreeMarkers();
    }
}
```

the landMarkMarkers() and TreeMarkers() checks if the map is null, if not it uses mMap.clear() then adds the new markers.

```
        private void landMarkMarkers() {
    float[] distance = new float[2];
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.clear();
    } else {
        Log.d("Maps: :", "mMap is null");
    }

    Marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(51.59757, -4.00102))
            .title("Entrance 1")
            .snippet("Entrance to the park.")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

    Marker2= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(51.59679, -4.00678))
            .title("Entrance 2")
            .snippet("Entrance to the park.")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));
```

in onMapReady i use longClickListener for people to add markers them self for places they find using the app. It uses EditActivity so they can label the marker.

```
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Intent edit = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
            edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
            MapsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
        }
    });

   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case (EDIT_REQUEST) : {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = data.getParcelableExtra("marker");
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
            break;
        }
```

My question is what can i do, So that when the user changes the spinner from trees to land marks or vice versa and opens and closes the app.The markers that have been added through LongClick will always appear on the map, i believe I need to add the markers into an array but i cant seem to get it work with the way i implemented it.
 Thanks for anyone who has the time, and please try and keep it simple. I'm still learning!

Answer (score 1):

Try collect all markers in collection and call Marker.remove() method for each except ones implemented with long click.

Comment: Do you have any idea how id implement that? where would i put this code, because whenever i try and edit the statement i use for the spinners i have multiple markers from trees and landmarks in the tree spinner

Comment: Add your marker into structure. For example: ```{ boolean isLongClick = true, Marker marker }```. And add this object in collection.

Comment: I believe the problem isn't with what i said previously. Whenever i open and close my app the long click goes.. doesn't matter if i clear the map using mMap. in onMapReady i use code with onClick. Do you know of a way to save that information, and re-open it when the app opens?

Comment: If you want to save data from current map state, use database.